# Email hosting on multiple servers

Tags: email, hosting, mx-record

I have a domain with hosting on godaddy while the domain is registered on BigRock. My email Ids are hosted on google apps, which was providing 10 free accounts some time ago. I wish to add few more email account, but that demands a business version of google apps. However, I have another hosting account which provides unlimited email hosting. I wanted to know if I can configure the MX records in such a way that my existing 10 accounts continue on google apps while the new ones are created on the new hosting account. So, any email addressed to this domain would be delivered on google apps if it exists there, otherwise on my new hosting.

thanks

bizdev

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to host some users on one mail server and the rest on the other, it's an all or nothing proposition.

Answer (score 0):

MX records do not support the level of granularity you require. An alternative may be to use email aliases on your Google Apps accounts to create new addresses and configure these forward elsewhere.

For example, given an existing Google Apps account accepting mail for users @example.com, you may be able to create a second Google Apps account accepting mail for users @mail2.example.com, and use email aliases on your primary account to redirect to user accounts on your secondary account. This is not an ideal solution however and will probably require customer per user configuration on the second account to ensure that sent mail is sent from the correct addresses.